# Average between-net variance from all possible ways of catching F fish in N nets

Tags: r

I hope the description is close enough to mathematical terms to be understood.
Here is my function in R.

```
ExpBetwNetVar <- function(nets,fish){
  if(nets==1 | fish == 0) return(0)
  q <- t(combn(rep(0:fish,nets),nets))
  r <- unique(q[apply(q,1,sum)== fish,])
  mean(apply(r,1,var)) 
  }
```

It seems to work, but it exhausts memory on my PC at about Nets = 5 and Fish = 16. a. Would others agree that the function works as described? b. Could it be made more efficient?
Thanks
JEL

Comment: Combn certainly does what it's supposed to. My problem is that with large inputs I'm storing many vectors that I subsequently exclude. The max inputs I think I need are (6,26). I suppose that for these remaining cases I can program 5 or 6 nested loops, generate prospective inputs sequentially, exclude each input that doesn't sum as required, and accumulate outputs. That method is more complicated but probably won't exhaust ram.

Comment: My function ExpBetwNetVar is erroneous because it doesn't weight the variances for specific nets and fish samples by the number of ways samples could be generated. (Stats review needed!)

Comment: I corrected my function to properly weight each sample variance by 'permutations' (the number of ways the sample could be drawn). The interesting result is that the weighted mean variance of all possible samples = fish / nets.